# How can I get similarity rate between columns in different dataframes and filter by some value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, nlp

I need to compute differences between rows in different dataframes. On one hand I have df1 with 150 different rows with specific phrases. On the other hand I have df2 with 250k of rows with any type of phrases. I want to compare each row in df1 with each row in df2 getting or labeling all the rows in df2 that have a value higher than a threshold (to be determinated) I use SequenceMatcher in order to get the similarity between them.

How could i do it? Any advice in order to do it in the more efficient way? How you code that?

df1 (len = 150)

| Phrases |
| --- |
| My cat is black |
| Dog is white |
| Peter is waiting |
| Dog is white |

df2 (len = 250k)

| Phrases |
| --- |
| My cat is white |
| Dog is jumping |
| Marcos is waiting |
| Dog is white |

Output:

| Phrases | Labels |
| --- | --- |
| My cat is white | 0.75 |
| My cat is white | 0 |
| My cat is white | 0 |
| My cat is white | 0.33 |
| Dog is jumping | 0.33 |
| Dog is jumping | 0.66 |
| Dog is jumping | 0.33 |
| Dog is jumping | 0.66 |
| Marcos is waiting | 0.33 |
| Marcos is waiting | 0.33 |
| Marcos is waiting | 0.66 |
| Marcos is waiting | 0.33 |
| Dog is white | 0.5 |
| Dog is white | 0.66 |
| Dog is white | 0.33 |
| Dog is white | 1 |

Comment: If you've found the to-go method for determining similarity it's a question about the most efficient way to apply a function on a `dataseries` which I believe is the `Pool` and concurrent processing!

Comment: I have this :
````
indice = []
similaridad = []
list_1 = list(df1)
for i in list_1 : 
    for contador, j in enumerate (list_2 , start = 0): 
        score = SequenceMatcher(None, i , df2['Phrases'][contador]).ratio() # 
        indice.append(contador)
        similaridad.append(score)
````